# PHP foreach sort by key / values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I jus't can't wrap my head around this. What I'm missing is the logical bit.

I have this $myArray :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(4) "en"
    ["url"]=>
    string(42) "http://feeds.feedburner.com/wordpress/haJM"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(4) "en"
    ["url"]=>
    string(37) "http://feeds.feedburner.com/hackaday/LgoM"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(4) "klingon"
    ["url"]=>
    string(36) "http://www.maitre-eolas.fr/feed/atom"
  }
}
```

So one array of unknown size, and each element is an array of know size, (2 key / value pairs (lang = something & url = something) the whole point is not knowing what lang is. It can really be *any* (alphanumerical) value.

And what I'd like to do is to build a new, clean array where keys are sorted by their name, like this :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["urls"]=>
array(2) {
  string(42) "http://feeds.feedburner.com/wordpress/haJM"
  string(37) "http://feeds.feedburner.com/hackaday/LgoM"
}
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(6) "klingon"
    ["urls"]=>
array(1) {
  string(36) "http://www.maitre-eolas.fr/feed/atom"
}
  }
}
```

But when I try to put the first $myArray[0]['lang'] in a variable and compare it with the following, it... Works. Once. And stops.

I'm doing it wrong, I *know* it.

Comment: Could you please post your code. We can't tell you what you're doing wrong and how to fix it otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$aResult = array();
foreach($aInput as $aRow){
    $aResult[$aRow['lang']][] = $aRow['url'];

}
```

That would give you:

```
array:
  'Klingon' 
      'URL1' 
      'URL2' 
  'en' 
      'URL1' 
      'URL2'
```

Do you really need the format listed above? Or will this do as well?

Comment: Wow. Works nickel, as we say here. Thanks a lot.